# Matlab: Export a figure made with myaa

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get better quality phase plots of complex functions made with the Complex Function Explorer of E. Wegert [CFE](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45464-complex-function-explorer). For this purpose I apply the Matlab anti-aliasing function [myaa.m](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20979-myaa-my-anti-alias-for-matlab) to the phase plots that are made with the CFEGUI.m. For the example screenshot of the result window below I used the setting myaa([8 8]) in the Matlab command window which means that the supersampling enlarge the figure 8x and then downscale it to 1/8 to get the original h x w.

As one can see the window of the figure has no operation icons or menu options for save or print. My question is what to do with such a figure (beside making screenshots)? Can I somehow use [export-fig](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) to save such a figure or load it in an image array and if yes, how?

It is also possible to use the setting myaa([8 1]) which results in a very large figure window that is larger than my screen (and has the unpleasant attribute that it can not be moved). It would be even better if such a whole figure could be saved (not only the visible part).

[image: myaa result window with phase portrait]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getframe` to grab current figure information in pixels.

However, while I do not know how this affects you, notice that MATLAB versions above 2014b (included) have already anti-aliasing. The code you linked seem to be from 2008, I am not 100% sure if it has become obsolete now.

Comment: I tested F = getframe; figure imshow(F.cdata); Positive is that the new figure has zoom&save&print options.Negative is that with myaa([8 1]) I get an error "The specified rectangle is not fully contained within the figure. MATLAB no longer supports this capability." and even myaa([8 8]) shows a warning "Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 67%".  The datatype of F is struct so I can't use imwrite directly. How can I transform/export F?

Comment: @GünterBachelier `F.cdata` is an image, as you clearly showed with `imshow`. You can `imwrite` that

Comment: @ Ander Biguri: imwrite(F.cdata, ...) worked. Thanks! And with some post-processing (imgaussfilt and imresize with a good custom interpolation kernel) I also got sufficient good quality results.

Comment: @GünterBachelier Consider accepting the answer as valid. The same for all your other posts

Comment: @GünterBachelier Next to the up and down arrow and the number of votes there is a green V like tick. That marks the answer as "the correct one" so future readers do know what did actually work