# Matlab: get a frame that is larger than the screen

Tags: matlab

In a recent context [(Export figure made with myaa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703121/matlab-export-a-figure-made-with-myaa) I got an error message applying getframe trying to capture a figure that is larger than the screen:

```
Error using getframe (line 98)
The specified rectangle is not fully contained within the figure. MATLAB no longer supports this capability.
```

Semantically this means that Matlab had at some point this capability and therefor there must be a version of getframe or some isolated code that is able to get a frame that is larger than the actual screen (I am using R2016b). Can someone help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `getimage` instead of using `getframe`.

Check the following example:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
I = imresize(I, [2048, 2048]); %Create large image.
figure;imshow(I);

%getimage returns 2048x2048 matrix.
J = getimage(gca);
imwrite(J, 'J.png'); %Save image.
```

Comment: Perfect! I could capture a 9056 x 7632 image!